# How to pass an additional parameter when the user singing up using devise? even it is not User coulmn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, devise-jwt

I want to send additional values when the user signs up and do some logic before creating the record using devise and devise-JWT in Rails API,
I used that https://rubydoc.info/github/heartcombo/devise/main/Devise/ParameterSanitizer to permit additional parameters

choice is not a  column in the User table.

application_controller

```
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    attributes = [:choice]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: attributes)
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: attributes)
  end


ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError (Error occurred while parsing request parameters):
```

Comment: "choice" is supposed to be an attribute of the User model. Is it in your migration?

Comment: But I don't want to be it as a column; is that possible

Comment: And if you add it to the params object in a before_action callback in application_controller?

Comment: How to that please?

Answer (score 0):

According to Devise documentation, you are able to generate custom Devise controllers, so you may put your own logic.

https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#getting-started

Comment: I did that and got this error that the parameter should belong to modedl model

Comment: I think you should put what you did in the main question, so I could help you better.

Comment: A question.  Can not do that into the application controller?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I added an attribute named "current_client_aplication_id" to the params object for respective request.  For knowing how do it, I had to inspect the params objct just in that line, using byebug for debuging.

```
#application_controller
before_action do
   session[:current_client_application_id] = "1"
   params[request["controller"].singularize]["client_application_id"] = session[:current_client_application_id] if params[request["controller"].singularize]
end
```

In this way, "current_client application_id" is available in all requests.